# How to prevent spliting of Table over mutliple pages in jspdf

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf

I am using jspdf for generating my pdf report. I have multiple tables which show the principle, but when I am generating the pdf, table's rows are splitting between different pages, the upper row in initial page and later in later page.

I want the full table in a single page if there is no enough space in one page move the whole table in next page.[image]

Comment: This is how to accept answers http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 1):

you have to check the actual page size always before adding new content

```
doc = new jsPdf();
...
pageHeight= doc.internal.pageSize.height;

// Before adding new content
y = 500 // Height position of new content
if (y >= pageHeight)
{
  doc.addPage();
  y = 0 // Restart height position
}
doc.text(x, y, "value");
```

Source: [MrRio/jsPDF/issues/101](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/101)